# Kenmore Dryer Won't Heat

Tags: dryer, heat

I have a Kenmore dryer that won't heat.  Here's what I know:

240 voltage comes into dryer.  Checked wires inside where power connects.

Thermostat, high limit thermostat, heating element, and fuses all have continuity

Lint tubes all clean.

Motor switch has continuity

WHAT COULD THIS BE?  Maybe the control board? (although doesn't look damaged or have any black marks from a surge and dryer buttons work fine)

Comment: Have you checked that power is sent to the heating element?

Comment: Motor turns the drum? What about the cutoff switch in the door?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys.  Isher - I checked the power flow to the element - no power.  Wayfaring - motor turns the drum.  Cut off switch is ok (I assume) because the drum turns

Comment: 240V is probably controlled by a relay; can you hear the relay "click"?

Comment: Much of the control board electronics are TTL or ECL, and you'll never see any damage even though ICs are blown. As Dan G commented, if you can find a relay in the line to the heater, see if that can be toggled.

Answer (score 1):

look for an thermal fuse on the heating element. If the coil over heated these thermal links pop cost from 5-15$ (as long as the heat coil is good) [This may be the cause.](https://www.zoro.com/whirlpool-dryer-thermal-fuse-3390719/i/G9702874/?gclid=CKqK6Lnv3M0CFY17fgodboIDVA&gclsrc=aw.ds). usually held in with screws easy to change.

Comment: Good idea, but OP mentions fuses.

Comment: yes but that one gets over looked quite often and,  it is the control for the heater relay so the wiring looks two small.

Comment: Just replaced one of those on a coffeepot. It's the most common cause of failure. There are two varieties, one shot, and resettable.